# How convert a JSONArray to a generic List<T>?

Tags: java, android, json

How convert a generic JSONArray to multiple types of List in one method?

like a:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject("....");
List<String> str = toList(o.optJSONArray("array1"));
List<Integer> mIntegers = toList(o.optJSONArray("array2"));
List<JSONObject> jsonO = toList(o.optJSONArray("array3"));
List<JSONArray> jsonAr = toList(o.optJSONArray("array4"));
```

Comment: @cse A List<T> regardless of what you define

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: tks! i Solve, checkout my answer, I hope it helps more people

Answer (score 3):

I solved my question ...

I hope it helps more people

```
public <T> List<T> toList(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (jsonArray != null) {
        int len = jsonArray.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            list.add((T) jsonArray.opt(i));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You should **never** use raw types in new code. Therefore, `new ArrayList()` is bad. Replace it with `new ArrayList<>()` and you're good to go. Also, `T extends Object` is unnecessary, since every type is a subclass of `Object`.